# How do I add minified bootstrap file in a typescript project?

Tags: css, typescript, bootstrap-4

I don't want to use react-bootstrap but add only the minified css. I copied the original css file in my project and I added the path in the index.html but it still doesn't work.

```
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
/>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<title>title</title>
<link
  href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  type="text/css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

I am using typescript with react.
How should I import minified files? I tried to add also other CSS frameworks, but it looks like I am importing them wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` to the app.ts. Solution here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/webpack/

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the ./ before assets on your link

Comment: Thank you I solved it by adding this import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; to app.ts